# How to speed a loop with a pandas.groupby.nth() in it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to speed a loop which used a `groupby.nth()` on a dataframe at each iteration.
Here is a quick explanation of my code:
Imagine that i want to perform Monte Carlo Simulation:

-> Let's say I have a dataframe df1 of weights of dimension 10*20. (weights of 10 assets that evolve over time, ie 20 years, sum on each columns = 1).

-> And df2 (see the image), another one which is 200.000 * 20. (First columns are Nan, since it's a dataframe of returns)

200.000 are data for my 10 assets placed in a row (20.000 rows each).

My code:
-loops through the number of simulation (0 < nb simulations < 20.000)

-groupby the df2 by asset

-create a dftemp = df2.groupby('asset').nth(i) and compute returns(i) by multiplying df1 * dftemp and summing the result on axis=0

```
Returns = np.zeros((nbsimulations,nbyears))
Capital = np.zeros((nbsimulations,nbyears))

    gb = datafilereturns.groupby('Asset')
    for i in range(0, nbsimulations):
        path = gb.nth(i)

        retsum = (TranspGrilleT.values * path.values).sum(axis=0)
        Returns[i,:] = retsum[1:]
    Capital[:,0] = Capital[:,0] * (1 + Returns[:,0])
```

My issue is that for a high number of simulation (20.000, ie the max since we don't have more than 20.000 data for each asset), the code is quite slow since it needs to use nth(i) in the loop, multiply values of df1 and dftemp and sum it at each step .

I tried to look at Cython and Numba to speed up the code but without any success. Could Numpy speed up that loop ? But in that case how to replace the nth(i) function from pandas?

Thank you for your help!

[dataset, ie df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asdh6.png)

Comment: why don't you use `groupby('Asset').head()` or `groupby('Asset').nlargest()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Because if i put the groupby('asset').head(i) in a loop, i have an increasing array since head(3) will give me three lines for each asset. groupby.nth(i) gives me one line for each asset, but the third one. 
Do you think we could make it faster in numpy ?

Comment: No, I mean you use `head(n)` and forget about the `for loop`.

Comment: But how to replace the multiplication of matrix values at each step ? ie the `retsum = (TranspGrilleT.values * path.values).sum(axis=0)`